# RSelenium - Could not determine server status - more advanced problem

Tags: javascript, r, server, rselenium

I have the following problem and I would be really thankful if someone here could help me.

I want to scrape data (links) from a java scripted website but do have a few problems with RSelenium. More concrete: with connecting to the server.

My code till now is the following.

```
## R Selenium ##

install.packages("netstat")

library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(netstat)

port1 <- 9515
port1 <- as.integer(port1)


## start the server ##
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                             port = free_port())
```

I do always get the error

```
"Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2252 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = free_port()) :
  Could not determine server status."
```

When im checking for the reason with the following code, it says

```
selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = FALSE)
selServ$log()
```

```
$stderr
[1] "Fehler: Hauptklasse c(-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"C:\\\\Users\\\\MarcF\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\binman\\\\binman_chromedriver\\\\win32\\\\113.0.5672.24.chromedriver.exe\", konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden"
[2] "Ursache: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: c(-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=\"C:\\\\Users\\\\MarcF\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\binman\\\\binman_chromedriver\\\\win32\\\\113.0.5672.24.chromedriver.exe\","                   

$stdout
character(0)
```

Does anyone know, how I can connect to the RSelenium Server? I really do need it for a project.

my session info:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] netstat_0.1.2   forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.0     purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.3.0    
 [8] tibble_3.1.8    ggplot2_3.4.1   tidyverse_1.3.2 RSelenium_1.7.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0    haven_2.5.1         gargle_1.2.1        colorspace_2.1-0    vctrs_0.5.2        
 [6] generics_0.1.3      yaml_2.3.7          utf8_1.2.3          rlang_1.0.6         pillar_1.8.1       
[11] withr_2.5.0         glue_1.6.2          DBI_1.1.3           rappdirs_0.3.3      dbplyr_2.2.1       
[16] readxl_1.4.1        semver_0.2.0        modelr_0.1.10       lifecycle_1.0.3     munsell_0.5.0      
[21] binman_0.1.3        gtable_0.3.1        cellranger_1.1.0    rvest_1.0.3         caTools_1.18.2     
[26] wdman_0.2.6         tzdb_0.3.0          ps_1.7.2            curl_5.0.0          fansi_1.0.4        
[31] broom_1.0.3         Rcpp_1.0.9          backports_1.4.1     scales_1.2.1        googlesheets4_1.0.1
[36] jsonlite_1.8.4      fs_1.5.2            hms_1.1.2           stringi_1.7.8       processx_3.8.0     
[41] grid_4.2.2          cli_3.4.1           tools_4.2.2         bitops_1.0-7        magrittr_2.0.3     
[46] crayon_1.5.2        pkgconfig_2.0.3     ellipsis_0.3.2      xml2_1.3.3          reprex_2.0.2       
[51] googledrive_2.0.0   lubridate_1.9.1     timechange_0.1.1    assertthat_0.2.1    httr_1.4.4         
[56] rstudioapi_0.14     R6_2.5.1            compiler_4.2.2
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the following approach. You need to install Docker to make it work.

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "a_url.com"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
```

You can also consder the following approach :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

url <- "a_url.com"
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDrPJS <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDrPJS$open()
remDrPJS$navigate(url)
```